# What makes aliens stronger?

Tags: factorio

What exactly makes aliens stronger?

Is it based on the in-game time, the technologies, the overall pollution or other factors I didn't mention?

Comment: This does not provide an answer, but is very relevant reading: **[Friday Facts #177 - Difficulty settings](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-177)**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few factors that go into the evolution of enemies. From [the Wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Enemies#Evolution), they include:

> - The passage of time very slightly increases the evolution factor.
> - The global Pollution Production increases the evolution factor.
> - Destroying the enemy spawners significantly increases the evolution factor.

You can type in one of these commands into the console to find out the current evolution factor:

`/c game.player.print(game.evolution_factor)`

or

`/evolution`

According to the Wiki, the `/evolution` command will not deactivate achievments, but the other one will. The evolution number can be between 0 and 1, where 1 is fully evolved. Currently, evolution does not go down ever.

The break down of evolution is as follows:

- One game tick - 0.0004%
- 1,000 pollution Units - 0.0015%
- Destroying a Spawner - 0.2%

Comment: All `/c` commands disables the achievements.