# Does increasing Game Speed count as using cheats in Factorio?

Tags: achievements, cheats, factorio

I know this is a silly question but when I am idle and just waiting for some thing to complete production or researching science for the matter, I want to increase the speed of the game.

I am used to increasing speed in games like Stronghold or Age of Empires and I am playing them a lot these days which makes me want to do the same thing in this game.

Considering the issue of using cheats switches off the achievement meter, will by increasing speed my game stop counting achievements?

Comment: Well, since you need to wait, you didn't automate enough stuff, so if the game considers it cheating, I think it's absolutely justified.

Comment: In the 360 hours of Factorio I played I can not remember a single moment where I couldn't think of anything to build, optimize or expand. When you have to *wait* for something to happen, your factory isn't productive enough. When your factory is not productive enough, you got to change that.

Comment: @Philipp probably in the early game when you don't have any electronics yet so you have to mine and kind of wait for the plates to be smelted (yes you can mine while you wait but honestly, that's not really the enjoyable part).

Comment: @A.Lau even in the early game you should be able to spend all your time running around, gathering items from smelters and placing more. You would have "nothing to do" for maybe a few seconds at best while you're waiting for an item to be crafted.

Comment: @A.Lau: The situation in your comment lasts until you have one burner miner + furnace setup for the important three: iron, coal and copper (imo you initially only need stone for furnaces and such an amount is easily mined manually). From that point on, every operation can be scaled. Whenever you find yourself waiting for resource X, spend that time on expanding the acquisition of resource X so you won't have to wait for it in the future. You will consistenly need more and more of a same resource as you progress, if you're already waiting now, you'll be waiting even longer in the future.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Yes what you said is definitely right. But my question remains.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. Using console commands or mods 
will permanently disable achievements on that save.

Comment: I think certain console commands don't disable them, but I'm not sure which.  [My answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300963/163757) to this question sites that the evolution command doesn't.  I wonder what else doesn't affect achievements.

Comment: @TimmyJim All `/c` commands, and only the `/c` commands, disable achievements. `/c` gives you access to the Lua console which makes it possible to do anything.

Comment: Using mods doesn't *disable* achievements, but games played with mods have a different set of achievements and won't show up in Steam for example.

Comment: @SimonForsberg That's correct for mods, but _console commands_ permanently disable all achievements for that save.

Comment: @duskwuff Agreed. As I said above, "All `/c` commands...."

Answer (score 5):

As stated in another answer, mods or console commands will disable Steam achievements. Although there's an alternative you could give a try.

You can most likely use a software like Cheat Engine, which will simulate a faster gameplay but probably not interfere with achievements as it's neither a mod nor a console command. The unique speed hack works by simulating a faster tick rate for your game than the game would normally have.

You could make the game ten times faster and *everything* would be ten times faster. This does mean the in game time will go by faster and you will move faster and the creatures will move faster.

The upside to this sort of hack is that your game will be simulated faster and waiting for stuff will not be such a bother. I used this software for clicker type games where it's *really* useful.

The downside is that you will be in slow motion compared to the game. So, when a creature that is simulated ten times faster than usual sees you, you will almost immediately die before you can react.

I'd like to add that if you're playing in multiplayer, the speed hack won't be of much use. Also, in case of singleplayer, you should cheat as much or as little as you want.

Comment: Could using this kind of speedhack in multiplayer cause de-sync issues? I'm guessing perhaps not as the game waits for the server every tick AFAIK. But what if you use speedhack on the server then? (Kids, don't try this at home.)

Comment: @SimonForsberg When we were playing, even under normal circumstances, there were desync issues if the internet connection of one person was slow enough. This might cause the same issue, especially if you're using it from the client side. Server side might be okay, depending on the internet connection of the clients. The game doesn't [shouldn't] wait for the server every tick (that would take too much data to send/receive) but rather checks up with the server every X seconds or when Y event happens. (I had written this as part of the answer but it was too long, so I scrapped that part.)

Comment: Confirming that Cheat Engine works for speedups (and slow-downs). If you''re having issues with a speed run, slowing down can help. OR, if you're doing an achievement like Lazy Bastard, it can help to be running quickly to get from place to place.

Comment: It also works in multiplayer if you're the server. Though if you speed it up too much, the game's communication can't keep up with the server and people start getting lag or dropped. The in-game speed-up cheat doesn't have this problem.